# Completion handler is not called

Tags: ios, swift

Pardon me for beginner's question, I have this function with a completion handler, but it's not called when the function complete. Any tip? thanks

```
    func updateDailyLength(completion: ()-> Void ) {
          //do something here
    }
```

And in the caller:

```
updateDailyLength(completion: { getMonthlyDistance() })
```

The function `getMonthlyDistance()` is never called.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to call it from `updateDailyLength`

```
func updateDailyLength(completion: ()-> Void ) {
      completion()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func updateDailyLength(completion: ()-> Void ) {
      completion()
}


updateDailyLength(completion: { getMonthlyDistance() })
```

You need to call the completion handler in the updateDailyLength() function. Once you call the function with the parameter as getMonthlyDistance() it is called in place of completion()